# Scroll content should be hidden

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

The problem is that I want to trim the content B scrolling in content A and when it scrolls down again, it should reappear.

So it should be the area invisible, which is pushed into content A. I suspect i will need javascript here or is this synonymous with css alone?

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/nature/grayscale');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;  
}

div { padding:10px; }

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height:100px;
  width:400px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.content {
  background:#fff;
  width:400px;
  height:1200px;
  margin-top: 220px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="fixed">
  Content A
</div>

<div class="content">  
  Content B
</div>
```

Thank you very much for helping!
Rufnex

Comment: It isn't very clear what the end effect is you want, please could you try to clarify it a little more

Comment: You can add `.content { position: relative; z-index: 12; }` if you want the scrolled div to appear on top. If you need anything more complex, you will have to use JavaScript

Comment: is this what u want?, `https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/`

Comment: Do you need to hide the content b when it is over content a?http://jsfiddle.net/mna4obfg/3/

Comment: I need an effect that makes the scrolled content part of div B invisible as soon as it scrolls into the bottom line of div A.

Comment: @Nitha i need it in the other direction div A should be visible and only the part of div B who scrolls into A should be hidden.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Lg6vyk5n/

Comment: @elveti I think opposite, hidden until it hits the box and then shown

Comment: @elveti wow, thats great. its nearly what i want to do. the content that scroll out of A on top should be also hidden. is this possible?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mna4obfg/4/

Comment: @Hannes yeah, kinda. You can use a pseudo element. Word of warning: it only works in this case, because the background image is attached as Fixed (so it's relative to the body), else it wouldn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/L6huoqxa/

Comment: @Nitha it behaves like the first example.

Comment: Sorry can you please check this one? http://jsfiddle.net/Lg6vyk5n/2/

Comment: @elveti That's great, it should be that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nitha thats nearly what i want. look at the answer from elveti http://jsfiddle.net/L6huoqxa/ thank you very much!